# Visual Studio Setup Project with VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, installation, vsto, setup-project

i've followed this Guide to create a Installer for a Office (Word) VSTO Addin: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022

The installer/uninstaller itself works fine, but after installing and starting word for the first time - incl. clicking the "Install" Dialogue for the Addin in Word - a seperate Program shows up with the Name of the Addin in the Control Panel.

When uninstalling the Addin with the custom Installer, this entry remains.
And the Addin can't be updated or reinstalled while this entry exists. I also found no way to remove this entry automatically without breaking something.

I think this entry is created when clicking "Install" in the Addin Dialogue in Word itself.

Can this be removed or bypassed with the Installer?
We want to distribute this Addin with a client automation software we're using and therefor a requirement is that everything must be accomplished with that setup.msi

Thanks
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

well in the Microsoft Documentation, there is a note that explicitly talks about this issue.

The Solution is appending a postfix to the manifest path: `|vstolocal`. This prevents ClickOnce from Caching.